# Switch the output order of list items from custom field

Tags: php, list, custom-fields

How can switch the order this outputs the list items. I have my custom field values set to "001,value" "002,value" but the lowest number comes out last in the list and I need it first.

```
 <?php
     $album = get_post_meta($post->ID, "album", false);
     $album_list = get_post_meta($post->ID, "album_list", false); 
     foreach ($album_list as $album_list) {
         list($key, $value) = explode(',',$album_list);
         $indexed_album_list[$key] = $value;
     }
     foreach ( $album as $each_album) {
         list($key,$album) = explode(',',$each_album);
         echo '<div>'.$album.'</div>';
         echo '<div>';
         if ($album_list = $indexed_album_list[$key]) {
             echo $album_list;
         }  
         else {
             echo '&nbsp';
         }
         echo '</div>';
     }
?>
```

Heres the returend data...`Array ( [0] => 002,Curtis [1] => 001,Get Rich Or Die Tryin [2] => 003,The Massacre [3] => 004,Before I Self Destruct ) Array ( [0] => 001, [1] => 002, [2] => 003, [3] => 004,`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the if statement in line 12 is supposed to use `==` not `=`. Also read the PHP manual pages of [asort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) and [ksort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh just had to add `sort($album);` on the fourth line and it worked.